# Algorithm for on road key points detection

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem with algorithm for detection points which leg on the road between source and destination points.

[image: Example part of road with marked key points]

There are a few assumptions for this:

1. Starting from p0 (starting point) I want to move to pk (destination point)
2. I have constraints for time and distance
3. All of key points (p1, p2, p3, ..., pn) have weight (profit) corresponding to them (w1, w2, w3, ..., wn)

The question is how to detect which points are the most profitable? When I choose some points I would like to ask google navigation API if constraints are fulfilled but requests are expensive so it would be better for me not to do many of these.
Do you know any algorithm which is designed for solving such a problem?

---EDIT 1---

If I well understood you I should modify my problem to graph.

[image: Transformation real road problem to graph]

Still I don't know algorithm which allows me to solve this problem.
This is two-way graph (excluding connection to point p0 and pk). I would like to maximize profit and keep distance restrictions. Do you know any formal algorithm which could help me with it?

Example paths could be:
p0->3->2->1->pk
p0->1->pk

Comment: Is there any reason why Dijkstra's would not work here?

Comment: If you can approximate time and distance using point coordinates (which should be reasonably cheap), you can calculate a preliminary profit-maximizing path given your constraints. Then, look up the real distances and times for the edges on your path and update. Iterate until you get a path that has the real distances and times.

Comment: Dijkstra works for graph. Here is situation where I have real road. I know only distances in straight line between points but not real. To know real distance I have to send request for google but I would like to avoid it to ask for all of roads.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Do you have any proposals how to approximate real distance between two coordinates? Important thing is that distance between points could be very small (0.5 km)

Comment: Just direct distance, measured through air.